# Get Last Update time using Unity API

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does Unity have a built in API to get the last update time for a mobile app or do I need to write a plugin? I only need this to work for iOS and Android.

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.PM.PackageInfo.LastUpdateTime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, no it does not.  It has no awareness of when it was installed.  You could try checking for the File CreationDate of specific files on launch.

Comment: I was just going to write a native plugin for iOS and Android. I've already written a few, but I'd like to avoid it if possible. Which files are updated during an app update? Would this approach be future proof?

Comment: A plugin would definitely be more reliable.  You technically have access to read the resources subfolders.  The Scene.Unity and other core data files will be modified and could reliably be considered modifiable on install by default.  For the code, something along these lines : `System.DateTime dateTime = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(path);` .  So, assuming you have something in Resources/fileinfo.txt, you should be able to use `System.IO.File.GetCreationTime("Resources/fileinfo.txt");`

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. The code I'm writing will be included in other projects that I don't control so it's possible they could do weird things that would change the creation time of the files so for my project it probably makes more sense to use a plugin. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looking into it more, it looks like the CreationDate doesn't work on all platforms...  So a plugin might have better long-term success too!